# How to make 1 image tile in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How can I make it so that a 100 by 100 image repeats itself all throughout the webpage. I want the image to duplicate itself and fill the screen.

for example lets say I had this picture:

[image]

and I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

The spacing doesn't matter, but how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a repeating background image in CSS. Then you can control the size of the image with `background-size`.

```
body {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtCRM.png') center center repeat;
    background-size: 2em;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/oculusriff/pen/VmZdzg

**Edit:** As per nicovank's comment - if you are new to CSS, here is the separated version of the above code.

```
body {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtCRM.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 4em;
}
```

Comment: Or you can separate by using `background-image`, and `background-repeat` if you are new to CSS. See [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: How would I do this for an img tag? here is my code so far: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBzRaX

Comment: This is not the desired look he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: FrankerZ - Obviously, but that is due to the image that was supplied. If the blue dot included the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right corners of another circle in it's corners, you would get the effect. It all comes down to how the repeating image tile is created in Photoshop.

Comment: Feen - You can make the image fill the screen by doing this #image_id { object-fit: cover; width: 100%; }

Comment: FrankerZ - Please don't down vote my answer when it is the correct one. The code is 100% correct, it's the image that is wrong.

Comment: Splurtcake - I don't want it to fill the screen. I want it to repeat. Your answer doesn't exactly work for my case.

Comment: @feen: You can't do tiling with an `img` tag unless you want to use JS, calculate screen sizes and append as many `img` tags etc.

Comment: @feen Harry is Correct. You could however use it as tiling CSS background image. http://codepen.io/oculusriff/pen/oYvyqm

Comment: @splurtcake if I do it like that, I can't change the image on click.

Comment: @feen Instead of putting the image on the body, you could put it on a full screen div and bind the click event to the div and change it with another CSS background image style.

Comment: @feen Also, clicking and changing the image is outside of the scope of the original question you asked, to which I answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I got to what I wanted. Sorry for not wording the question right.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBzRaX

I don't know what is making it repeat, but I think it's this. Now I just have to figure out how to make the button fit the whole screen. The button is only a sliver at the top right now.

```
document.body.style.background = "url('"+links[i]+"')";
```

Comment: You are effectively doing just what Splurtcake had mentioned but with JS instead of CSS. The JS just sets the `background` of the `body` tag and since the `background-repeat` property's default value is `repeat`, it would automatically tile.